# node.js connection will be closed if the user changed the page

Tags: node.js

i have progged a community.
At the Login.php i connect and listen via

```
var socket = io.connect("http://ajkfh.com:8080");
socket.on("connect", function() { ......
```

but then, if the user changed on another site from the community, his connection will be closed and he is not longer listen.

how can i hold open the connection over underlying sites of the community. THANKS and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

A socket connection is available only when the user remains on the page. There is no way for you to make a socket connection available across page loads. What you can do, is emulate page loads into ajax requests which load content inside a container.
Or you could just re-establish connection on page load, and have a mechanism to keep a track of clients (storing a client ID on a cookie or something)

Answer (score 0):

Seemed you use socket.io, which is websocket. The websocket connection does lost if the page refreshed or closed.

If you want to retain something between pages, use Cookie or Session, just like the normal http way. And on browser side, you can read the data out(e.g. via the document.cookie or some lib) and send back to the server over websocket.